# Excel complex formula name lookup based on numbers and ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula for the `Name Lookup` column in the `Lookup Table` below.

As shown below, the `Names Table` may have empty rows and the `N` column may include ranges, numbers separated by commas, and numbers out of order. Each table is an Excel formatted Table and may have more rows or less rows. Thank you very much for your help!

**Names Table**

| Name |
| --- |
|  |
|  |
| Jon Doe |
|  |
| Jane Doe |
| Micky Mouse |
|  |
|  |
| Donald Duck |
|  |
| Minnie Mouse |

**Lookup Table**

| N | Name Lookup |
| --- | --- |
| a | Jon Doe, Jane Doe, Micky Mouse, Donald Duck, Minnie Mouse |
| 1,3,4 | Jon Doe, Micky Mouse, Donald Duck |
| 1-3, 5 | Jon Doe, Jane Doe, Micky Mouse, Minnie Mouse |
| 2, 4-5, 1 | Jane Doe, Donald Duck, Minnie Mouse, Jon Doe |

Comment: What exactly does the `N` column represent? What is "a", what is 1, 3, 4, etc. Are we supposed to think that "a" means "all", and that numbers represent data that is populated?

Comment: N column is where the user enters data to trigger the Name Lookup. "a" means show all names. Numbers including ranges means lookup the names from above with each number corresponding to the order of the names in the Names Table.

Comment: So you plan to allow someone to arbitrarily input values in the `N` lookup cell? What if they input 1x instead of 1 or 4:6 instead of 4-6? Is there any sort of validation performed? Why would someone want to randomly select rows 1, 3 and 4? Wouldn't they want to search for something more concrete?

Comment: Yes, the user can input numbers separated by commas, or ranges separated by hyphens, or a combination of those. This is one part of a much bigger project. I understand the issues of data validation. It's ok if the formula generates an error if the user enters erroneous inputs. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So use the wildcard * .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solved this. This formula supports numbers separated by commas but not number ranges separated by hyphens. It also supports empty rows.

This was really hard for me and took a lot of effort. The formula is below. For my needs, "; " is used to separate each value, but it can obviously be changed to whatever separator someone needs.

I solved this myself and could not find this solution anywhere online. The resources online are especially lacking for this, which provides all values in a single cell rather than other online solutions that require multiple rows of cells and copying and pasting the formula down.

```
=IF([@N]="a",
TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,NamesTable[Name]),
TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,
INDEX(FILTER(NamesTable[Name],NamesTable[Name]<>""),
MATCH(NUMBERVALUE(TEXTSPLIT([N],,",",TRUE,1)),
ROW(NamesTable[Name])-ROW(NamesTable[[#Headers],
[Name]]),0))))
```

This is a lookup where you can enter **multiple lookups in one cell** and this formula returns **multiple matches in one cell.**